# Authenticated scans using ZAP when POST url isn't available

Tags: authentication, post, get, zap

I have been using the POST method to perform authenticated scans using ZAP. How could I do this using GET or when the POST url isn't available?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You've encountered an app that's sending creds via GET?

Comment: Yes there appears to be no POST:login url

Comment: You could create a authentication script that uses the GET url, or a script (or manybe a replacer rule) which changes the POST auth request to a GET.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Simon, I've taken your advice on this and will see how it goes. If you know any writeups or resources relevant to this, please share it with me, would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: You're aware of the security issue around a GET based authentication scheme?

Comment: No I'm not as I'm fairly new to this